# Why am I getting an unexpected return code?

Tags: perl

I have a Perl script with the following code.

```
...
$kill = 1;
$exit = 0;
`kill -9 $pid >& /dev/null`;
...
print "kill=$kill exit=$exit\n";
if ($kill) {
  exit $exit;
} else {
...
```

In summary, this script uses open3() to run a command. At some point, it kills the job and then the intention is that the script will exit with code 0. I inserted a print statement to show the values of variables `$kill` and `$exit`, which is shown below.

```
kill=1 exit=0
```

Since `$kill` is 1, I would expect the script to exit with code 0 above, since `$exit` is 0. However, the script exits with code 9, which is the signal sent to the child. Why is the Perl script exiting with the exit code of the child, instead of that which is given to the `exit()` call?

Comment: Orthogonal, but it's not a good idea to use -9 as a `kill` argument except in the direst of emergencies. You're denying the process the right to perform any cleanup tasks that might be necessary.

Answer (score 0):

From [here](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/exit.html):

> The exit() function does not always exit immediately. It calls any defined END  routines first, but these END  routines may not themselves abort the exit. Likewise any object destructors that need to be called are called before the real exit.

Comment: So how can I make it exit with the desired code, while still killing the child?

Comment: Irrelevant.  Because he's sending `SIGKILL` (`kill -9`), the Perl process is forcibly terminated by the kernel and not allowed to run **any** shutdown or cleanup code.  `exit` isn't even called - as soon as that `SIGKILL` hits, it's all over before the Perl code knows what hit it.